# Accessing enum from objects

Tags: mysql

Hey guys am new to mysql development..I hve wrote some code like

```
 CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2), 
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);


INSERT INTO  CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)  
VALUES (1,'aff',2,3,5);



set @a := CASE WHEN NAME = 'aff' THEN 5 ELSE 3 END;
```

when i run the varibale `@a` it throws error like `Schema Creation Failed: Unknown column 'NAME' in 'field list':`

Can anyone help me ..An sql fiddle example would be realy apreciated ..Thanx

Comment: What do you mean by `objects` in your title? and also I don't see where you use enums.

Answer (score 1):

To get something from a table, you have to use a `SELECT` query:

```
SET @a := (SELECT CASE WHEN name = 'aff' THEN 5 ELSE 3 END
            FROM CUSTOMERS
            LIMIT 1);
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a9d7/4)

When using a `SELECT` as an expression, it must only return 1 row, that's why I added the `LIMIT 1` clause.

Comment: @JNevill Your fiddle is empty. I created one of my own.